# SP10: Is SharePoint restricting some display method?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-online

I am trying to continue over the SharePoint of the enteprise I am working in. The problem I got is that what I enter in the Text Editor as HTML and STYLE doesn't appear like it does on Chrome or in Explorer, even if I use SharePoint in Explorer.

```
<div class="directeurs">
<div class="directeur">
    <img src="/sites/gest-vpteimd/telecommunications/BiblioDPTImage/DirecteurDSS.png" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur maxime impedit amet labore facere. Quod quos consectetur nulla eaque soluta tenetur omnis quo sunt, modi optio iste consequuntur atque error.</p>
    <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x70" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="directeur">
    <img src="/sites/gest-vpteimd/telecommunications/BiblioDPTImage/DirecteurDSEOT1.png" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus rem delectus enim dolorem, error nulla earum maxime aliquid ipsam, recusandae molestiae ducimus iusto, dolore omnis. Saepe temporibus autem, provident dolor!</p>
    <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x70" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="directeur">
    <img src="/sites/gest-vpteimd/telecommunications/BiblioDPTImage/DirecteurDECIT1.png" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis mollitia est nam aut velit minus ab, earum, labore perferendis ipsam cupiditate neque totam dolor fuga autem laudantium dolores reprehenderit perspiciatis.</p>
    <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x70" alt=""></a>
</div>
<div class="directeur">
    <img src="/sites/gest-vpteimd/telecommunications/BiblioDPTImage/DirecteurDSTT1.png" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam nesciunt minima, veritatis fugiat iure repudiandae blanditiis maxime adipisci autem, molestias, ut laudantium tempore expedita provident, quae possimus odit ab sapiente.</p>
    <a href=""><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x70" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

This is the HTML that I use.

```
        .directeurs /* Permet aux éléments "directeurs" d'obtenir la méthode d'affichage Flex. */ { 
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap
    }
    .directeur /* Permet aux éléments "directeur" d'obtenir la méthode d'affichage Flex, d'ajuster leur taille à 50% et d'aligner le tout au centre. */ {
      width: 50%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .directeur p /* Permet aux éléments p descendant de "directeur" d'avoir une taille de 80%, d'être centrer et d'avoir un espace au dessus et en dessous. */ {
      width: 80%;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .directeur a /* Permet d'ajuster l'espace au dessus de l'objet a descendant de "directeur". */ {
      margin-top: auto;
    }
    .directeur a > img /* Permet aux éléments img l'intérieur de a descendant de "directeur" d'être positionné au centre ainsi que d'avoir un espace sous eux. */{
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      display: block;
    }
```

And this is the style. 
Normally, everything should be aligned like so :
[image: How it should be aligned]
And it appears like so :
[image: How it is at the moment]

And if by any chance someone knows how to erease that big blank white space in my text editor I would appreciate !

Comment: I know that the image are too big and take the space, but even when I set them to max-width:450px, they don't go side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that Flex-Wrap might not work as intended. so I switched the code a bit and it's all working now.

```
.directeurs /* Permet aux éléments "directeurs" d'obtenir la méthode d'affichage Flex. */ { 
      display: block;
    }
    .directeur /* Permet aux éléments "directeur" d'obtenir la méthode d'affichage Flex, d'ajuster leur taille à 50% et d'aligner le tout au centre. */ {
      width: 50%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      float: left;
    }
```